# How do I resize an image for a 960 grid web design?

Tags: css, image, web

On my website I have a slider of images across the top. This is the demo of the drupal theme (the company, not my website),

http://demo.drupalizing.com/?theme=bluemasters

All my pictures are different sizes or different kinds of shots. I don't know how to say it. I can re-size in any program. If I keep the aspect ratio, the 960px will be fine, but the bottom will be stretched.

How do I keep it all good and fit it in 960?

If not 960, what is a good number or other type of design?

Can I use CSS?  Do I use an image program like Gimp, Paint.net, etc.?

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /b...masters_drupal was not found on this server.

Comment: Sigh.  It has been running forever until I asked about it.  It figures.  Thanks.

Comment: Added an edit to correct your link. Now, back to the regular scheduled program.

Answer (score 2):

As long as all your pictures are larger than 960px in width you can use HTML or CSS markup to resize the image to 960px. However, please remember that there is no way to display the an entire image say 4000x2000 in a 960px box without making it look small or choppy. In this case I would use an image editing program and cut out the main focus of the image and save it as a 960x300 (or whatever height) image.

Answer (score 1):

From your link, the slider images are all 930px x 320px.  You can use CSS to overcome this limitation, but your images might stretch out of proportion.

I would start with a an art work that is 930px x 320px, and just crop your photos according to this aspect ratio.

In this BlueMaster theme, the CSS already has a width set to 100% so no need to worry about scaling.

Online photo editor tool: http://pixlr.com/editor/

- File -> New Image
- Width -> 930
- Height -> 320